# Debug break points not functioning within Django class methods but working fine with scripts

Tags: debugging

I am a beginner in Django, and I've recently created a CRUD API using Django. However, I'm facing an issue when I try to debug the API using PyCharm and VSCode. The problem is that the breakpoints I set inside the class methods of my views are not being hit during debugging.

I've successfully used breakpoints in non-class-based views and regular Python scripts before, so I'm wondering if there's something specific to class-based views that I might be missing.

Here i attaching my github repo https://github.com/madhusoodhananer/djangoCrud.git

This is my view.py

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status, generics
from note_api.models import NoteModel
from note_api.serializers import NoteSerializer
import math
from datetime import datetime


class Notes(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = NoteSerializer
    queryset = NoteModel.objects.all()

    def get(self, request):
        page_num = int(request.GET.get('page', 1))
        limit_num = int(request.GET.get('limit', 10))
        start_num = (page_num - 1) * limit_num
        end_num = page_num * limit_num
        search_param = request.GET.get('search')
        notes = NoteModel.objects.all()
        total_notes = notes.count()
        if search_param:
            notes = notes.filter(title__icontains=search_param)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(notes[start_num:end_num], many=True)
        return Response({
            'status': 'success',
            'total_notes': total_notes,
            'page': page_num,
            'last_page': math.ceil(total_notes / limit_num),
            'notes': serializer.data
        })

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({
                'status': 'success',
                'data': {
                    'note': serializer.data
                }
            }, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response({
                'status': 'fail',
                'message': serializer.errors
            }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class NoteDetail(generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = NoteModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NoteSerializer

    def get_note(self, pk):
        try:
            return NoteModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except:
            return None

    def get(self, request, pk):
        note = self.get_note(pk=pk)
        if note is None:
            return Response({
                'status': 'fail',
                'message': f'Note with id {pk} not found'
            }, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        serializer = self.serializer_class(note)
        return Response({
            'status': 'successful',
            'data': {
                'note': serializer.data
            }
        }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def patch(self, request, pk):
        note = self.get_note(pk)
        if note is None:
            return Response({
                'status': 'fail',
                'message': f'Note with id {pk} not found'
            }, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        serializer = self.serializer_class(note, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({
                'status': 'success',
                'data': {
                    'note': serializer.data
                }
            }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({
                'status': 'fail',
                'message': serializer.errors
            }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk):
        note = self.get_note(pk)
        if note is None:
            return Response({
                'status': 'fail',
                'message': f'Note with id {pk} not found'
            }, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        note.delete()
        return Response({
            'status': 'success',
            'message': f'Note with id {pk} deleted'
        }, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

This is my debug config and breakpoint
[image]
[image]
[image]

*During debugging, the first breakpoint is successfully caught, but the second breakpoint inside the function is not being caught, debugger never enters in that function but response have data *

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Ensured that the breakpoints are set correctly: I've made sure that the breakpoints are set at appropriate locations inside the class methods of my views.
2. Debug configuration: I've set up the debugging configuration in both PyCharm and VSCode to target my Django project and run the development server with debugging enabled.